# Refresh a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I have a `v-for` loop with a **fixed number** of loops to set each cell of a css grid:

```
<div v-for="(foo, i) in 34"
  :key="bar+'-'+i"
  :class="setClass(i)"
  @click="myMethod(i)">
  {{ i }}
</div>
```

Above this `div`, I have a `select` input box bind to a v-model variable `bar`. How should I re-render my `v-for` loop when the select value has changed ?

Comment: Add a key which depends on the bar variable

Comment: What kind of values your are selecting in the select box, Do you need to replace 34 with some selected values?

Comment: @SimonThiel I tried it but it doesn't re-render the loop (I updated the code in my question about it).

Comment: @chans I don't need to replace the 34, just to re-render the loop because the `setClass` method depends on the `bar` variable.

Comment: Can you share the complete component code, So that I can create a codepen..

Comment: If `bar` is defined in your `data` it will automatically trigger a re-render when the value changes. You don't need to do anything special, if `setClass` touches `bar` it will be registered as a rendering dependency.

Comment: My problem came from refreshing `bar`, indeed when `bar` is in `:key` and changed, the `v-for` is refreshed. Should I delete this question ?